# Configure varnish with apache on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, caching, varnish

I have been trying to install Varnish on ubuntu 18.04. I have used this article https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-setup-varnish-http-cache-on-an-ubuntu-18-04-vps-or-dedicated-server/,

after I run the command `curl -I http://localhost` but I get the error `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`.

**/etc/default/varnish**

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
     -T localhost:6082 \
     -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
     -S /etc/varnish/secret \
     -s malloc,256m
```

**/etc/varnish/default.vcl**

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "80";
```

Results of curl -I http://localhost:8080

```
curl -I http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
ETag: "29cd-56dff9168052e"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 10701
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

the output of `sudo service varnich restart` is `Failed to restart varnich.service: Unit varnich.service not found.`

how can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Based on the new info the problem is the Varnish VCL config. It's missing alot of information.

Here is an example VCL modified according to your setup

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PRI") {
    /* We do not support SPDY or HTTP/2.0 */
    return (synth(405));
    }
    if (req.method != "GET" &&
      req.method != "HEAD" &&
      req.method != "PUT" &&
      req.method != "POST" &&
      req.method != "TRACE" &&
      req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
      req.method != "DELETE") {
        /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
        return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
        return (pass);
    }
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        /* Not cacheable by default */
        return (pass);
    }
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    # By default Connection: close is set on all piped requests, to stop
    # connection reuse from sending future requests directly to the
    # (potentially) wrong backend. If you do want this to happen, you can undo
    # it here.
    # unset bereq.http.connection;
    return (pipe);
}

sub vcl_pass {
    return (fetch);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_purge {
    return (synth(200, "Purged"));
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        // A pure unadultered hit, deliver it
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
        // Object is in grace, deliver it
        // Automatically triggers a background fetch
        return (deliver);
    }
    // fetch & deliver once we get the result
    return (miss);
}

sub vcl_miss {
    return (fetch);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    return (deliver);
}

/*
 * We can come here "invisibly" with the following errors: 413, 417 & 503
 */
sub vcl_synth {
    set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set resp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    synthetic( {"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>"} + resp.status + " " + resp.reason + {"</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error "} + resp.status + " " + resp.reason + {"</h1>
    <p>"} + resp.reason + {"</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
"} );
    return (deliver);
}

#######################################################################
# Backend Fetch

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    return (fetch);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
      beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
      beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
      (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
        beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store|private") ||
      beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        /*
        * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
        */
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
    set beresp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set beresp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    synthetic( {"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>"} + beresp.status + " " + beresp.reason + {"</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error "} + beresp.status + " " + beresp.reason + {"</h1>
    <p>"} + beresp.reason + {"</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: "} + bereq.xid + {"</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
"} );
    return (deliver);
}

#######################################################################
# Housekeeping

sub vcl_init {
}

sub vcl_fini {
    return (ok);
}
```

Replace the contents in your **default.vcl** with this and then restart Varnish.

---

There isn't any service listening on `localhost:80`

Double check that Varnish is running

```
$ ps aux | grep varnish
```

If Varnish is running then you have to check the Varnish config

```
$ sudo cat /etc/default/varnish
```

Should print something like

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

Where the key is `-a :80`

Also make sure that your `Varnish service` have the same port config

```
$ sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service

[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/ man:varnishd
[Service]
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f$
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/varnishreload
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then try to restart Varnish

```
$ sudo systemctl restart varnish
```

**Tip**

You can verify that Apache is working by curling on port `8080`

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: thanks @Jacob for your answer, but what's the difference between your answer and the insrtuction in the article ?
I tried but still varnish not working on http://localhost:8080

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki Well the answer is just that the problem is that there is no service listening on that port. The other part is just to verify the installation :)
Do you get the same `curl` result when trying port 8080?

Comment: I tried `curl -I http://localhost:8080` but there isn't any information about varnish ?

Comment: But do you get a `200` response or nothing at all?

Comment: I get 200 response

Comment: I get the same response before I installed varnish, X-Varnish doesn't display in the response

Comment: Ok, good then we've verified that there isn't an issue in Apache. Could you please add your config from `/etc/default/varnish` and your whole varnish VCL config file and also the output from the command `ps aux | grep varnish`

Comment: after the installation, as in the article, in the file `/etc/default/varnish` I just edit `DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \ `  with  `DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \`

Comment: Could you please post them anyway? Also the output from `ps aux | grep varnish` and your VCL config file. Your VCL file is usually located in `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`

Comment: And also the output from `sudo systemctl restart varnish`

Comment: the output of `sudo service varnich restart` is 
`Failed to restart varnich.service: Unit varnich.service not found.`

Comment: You have a small typo in your script, it should be `sudo service varnish restart`

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is faulty to begin with.

In the **DAEMON_OPTS** you've set varnish to listen on port 80, while in the default.vcl you're configuring a backend for varnish which should listen on the same 80 port.

This will lead into a neverending loop.

In your case, you want to set apache as a backend for varnish. As you've configured apache to run on port 8080, you'll need to reflect this in the **default.vcl**

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
```

Do a `sudo service varnish restart` afterwards.

Comment: stil the same problem

Comment: What's the current problem now? Not being able to curl varnish on port 80? Or ``Failed to restart varnish.service: Unit varnish.service not found``